# MongoError: Authentication failed. Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I'm running a node and mongodb docker application on my machine, but when I try to connect to the database using moogose it returns:

```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (D:\Node\08-multi-dbb-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:272:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at processIncomingData (D:\Node\08-multi-dbb-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (D:\Node\08-multi-dbb-mongodb\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:435:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:419:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:309:11)
    at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:728:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  name: 'MongoError'
}
```

Here's how I'm making the connection:
file name: mongodb.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/dbname', 
    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function (error){
        if(!error) return;
        console.log('Falha na conexao!', error)
    }
)

const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open', () => console.log('database rodando!!'))
```

I can access the Database through the client (visual interface) and I can also connect to the Database through the terminal, for example

```
docker exec -it 347b053d4320 mongo -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase myDb
```

But when I try for the code running the mongodb.js file, it returns the error.

If you can help me out of kindness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends where you are making the connection from and how your Docker configuration looks like.

### Separate Docker Containers

Suppose you have Mongo in a Docker Container and NodeJS in another Docker Container.

If you do the connection from NodeJS then Mongo is not running on localhost.

### NodeJS and Mongo in seaparate Containers but in the same docker-compose file

Again looking from the NodeJS-standpoint,  Mongo is not running on localhost but on the service in docker-compose

Example

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  myapp:
    image: img_myapp:latest
    build:
      context: ./build/
    container_name: myapp
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - "8091:80"
    networks:
      - myapp-network

  database:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongo'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydb
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports: 
      - "27999:27017"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data/db
    networks:
      - myapp-network


networks:
  myapp-network:
```

In the above config you connect to mongodb://root:root@database:27999/mydb

### Running Mongo in a container and NodeJS on the host

In that case you can connect to localhost if mongo-container published its port. Which it did in the above yml: port 27999